# What are the differences between 間中{あいだじゅう} and 間{あいだ}?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances, time

I recently learned different usages of both kanji and I saw it is possible to use the combination of both. It seems to me that 間中{あいだじゅう} isn't a new word. (The other readings don't matter now.)

Here are a couple of examples which contain 間中{あいだじゅう}:

> 山田さん は テレビ を 見{み}ている間中{あいだじゅう} 食{た}べていました。
> Mr. Yamada was eating while watched the TV.

> デートの間中{あいだじゅう} 天気{てんき} が 悪{わる}かった。
> The weather was bad during the date.

I know these examples have the same meaning if I leave out 中{じゅう} because in this case 間{あいだ} still expresses that the statement happened from the start to end of the particular period. So I think here 中{じゅう} has been used to emphasize the fact that the statement happened for the whole particular period. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, 間中 is more emphatic, and indicates something happens from the start to the end of the period. Most of the time, you can translate ～の間 simply as "during ～", and ～の間中 as "throughout ～", "all through ～" or "during the entire ～". ずっと has the same function.

- 夜の間
  during the night
- 夜の間中 / 夜の間ずっと / 夜の間中ずっと
  all through the night / throughout the night / during the entire night
- 寝ている間
  while sleeping
- 寝ている間中 / 寝ている間ずっと / 寝ている間中ずっと
  the entire time one is sleeping / the whole time sleeping

Comment: I have a question: isn't 「の間中ずっと」rather redundant?

Comment: @Nameless It's true that using one of the two is usually enough, but IMHO using both is not unnatural when you want to speak emphatically.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to make sure as I've always seen it written as 間ずっと.

Comment: @nameless BTW, what do you feel about "all through the entire night"? Is it redundant or unnatural?

Comment: It's idiomatic but emphatic, check here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/through?q=Through Scroll down to the second usage. You can also find examples on Google Books.

Comment: @naruto Not sure which usage Nameless is referring to in the link but personally I find "all through the entire night" rather awkward sounding. If I wanted to be more emphatic I think "throughout the entire night" sounds more natural.

Comment: @user3856370 This usage: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151510/all-through-the-night-all-over-the-night By adding *the entire night*, you're just being more emphatic as opposed to just saying *the night*, or atleast that's how I see it.

Comment: @Nameless I wonder where you are from? For me, as a UK native, it sounds very strange. I think it's the combination of 'all' and 'entire' that's jarring with me. Maybe it sounds more natural where you come from.

Comment: @naruto If I were to give you an actual answer, I would go with what *user3856370* said. For me, it wouldn't sound off in an informal context, just redundant emphasis.

Comment: Thanks, so looks like it's at least much worse than の間中ずっと :)